# Drop down list and button not working

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I have the HTML segment:

```
<select id="myList">
<option value="1"selected="selected">Position 1</option>
<option value="2">Position 2</option>
<option value="3">Position 3</option>
<option value="4">Position 4</option>
<option value="5">Position 5</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" id="go" value="Go to Position"></input>
```

Which prompts the user to select a position for a spotlight. The JS side contains this:

```
var select = document.getElementById("myList");
var answer = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;

if (answer == "1") {
    document.getElementById("go").onclick = function () { ightAtX = -1.0; lightAtZ = 0.5; };
} else if (answer == "2") {
    document.getElementById("go").onclick = function () { lightAtX = -1.0; lightAtZ = -0.5; };
} else if (answer == "3") {
    document.getElementById("go").onclick = function () { lightAtX = 0.0; lightAtZ = -0.5; };
} else if (answer == "4") {
    document.getElementById("go").onclick = function () { lightAtX = 1.0; lightAtZ = -0.5; };
} else if (answer == "5") {
    document.getElementById("go").onclick = function () { lightAtX = 1.0; lightAtZ = 0.5; };
} else {
    return; 
}
```

I want the user to click the 'Go to Position' button in order to change the position of the spotlight. However, when I click the button, nothing changes. What am I missing?

Comment: submit button will cause a post back

Comment: Missing L in the first if statement?

Comment: You have your event handling all turned around. Just select the`go` element, give it an `onclick` function, and inside that function, select the `answer` and set the variables based on its value. [Like this.](https://jsfiddle.net/461g6hba/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the selection (answer) inside of the onclick function.  The answer is evaluated once (unless there's more code not included), and wont be dynamically updated unless you tell it to.

Something like this:

```
document.getElementById("go").onclick = function () { 
    var select = document.getElementById("myList");
    var answer = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;

   if (answer == "1") {
   }...
}
```

Comment: No problem.  If this did fix your problem, please select this as the correct answer :)